# Reordering Navigation menu

Tags: navigation, css, top-link-bar, links-list

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I'm not sure if this issue is due to some of my css editing or i'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to rearrange the links in the navigation menu. Moving the links at the top level is fine, but creating a drop down is where I'm failing. I've tried hovering one link over the other but nothing happens.

Is there another way to arrange the parent-child order in the main navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using structured navigation? If so you can change the order in the navigation settings of the parent site. Or are you using managed navigation based on the term store in SharePoint 2013? If that is the case I suggest reordering the items directly in the term store.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Navigation menu in Site Settings. Am I right in thinking it should appear under Look and Feel?